# How to wrap links in <a> with Notepad++ Find/Replace function?

Tags: html, regex, replace, notepad++

I have a text document with raw links (not wrapped) and I would like to wrap them in HTML anchor tags.

**Link example:**

```
http://example.com/images/my-image.jpg
```

**Desired output:**

```
<a href="http://example.com/images/my-image.jpg">http://example.com/images/my-image.jpg</a>
```

---

I can **FIND** the links in Notepad++ using the following RegEx:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(\?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)|)
```

However, the **REPLACE** string I'm trying is not working for some reason:

```
<a href="\1">\1</a>
```

[image: This is the image for find dialog in Notepad++]

How can I do this with notepad++?

Comment: Did you try `$` sign instead of `\\`? `<a href="$1">...`?

Comment: The `$` is producing the same result. have you tested it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace with the backreference to the whole match:

```
<a href="$&">$&</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="$0">$0</a>
```

Here, the `$0` and `$&` "insert" the text that is matched by the whole regular expression, not just by some capturing groups.

Comment: Actually, I have some notes on the expression: there are two cases of `//` - I guess only one was meant. Also, a `+` does not have to be escaped inside `[...]`. If you intended to match a ``\``, you need to double it there: ``\\``